# How to create a timer in android programmaticaly?

Tags: java, android, timer, clock, alarm

I want to create an intent in android, which go to the timer application and input directly the numbers. I've tried this code, but it only starts the timer application, but not enter the numbers.

```
Intent intent = null;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_TIMER);

      intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR,hour);
      intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES,minutes);
      intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI,true);
      startActivity(intent);
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks for every response.

Comment: read the documentation please? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#ACTION_SET_TIMER

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is nothing that can be added in an answer that is not already plainly covered in the documentation.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry. I not saw this documentation before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR` and `AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES` are for **`AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM`.**

**`AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_TIMER`** only supports the extras `AlarmClock.EXTRA_LENGTH`, `AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE` and `AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI`

---

I suppose you don't want to create a timer (a.k.a. a counter that counts the seconds from the start) but instead you'd like to create a countdown. For this, I'd use a `CountDownTimer`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

You can even embed it in your own app instead of launching an external clock app.

Comment: how can I stop the timer started using `AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_TIMER`?

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html), the flag `ACTION_SET_TIMER` does not have the flags you are trying to use as optional request parameters. For the ones you are using you should be setting the `ACTION_SET_ALARM` flag.

Comment: how to stop the timer started using `AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_TIMER`?